# Css absolute positioned element over background image (responsive)

Tags: css, responsive-design, background, css-position, absolute

I have a responsive background image, so its width and height changes when resizing the screen. Over that background, there's an element with position absolute.
Now, my problem is that when resizing the screen, the absolute positioned element doesn't follow its place over the background image...

This is my HTML code:

```
<section id="all">

  <div id="clicked1">
    <img class="box" src="factory.svg" width="100%" height="auto">
  </div>

</section>
```

CSS:

```
#all {
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
  position: relative;
  max-width: 1240px;
  background: url('beach_to_meter.svg') no-repeat;
}
#clicked1 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 27%;
  top: 28%;
  z-index: 100;
  width: 200px;
}
#clicked1 .box {
  width:14vw;
  max-width: 180px;
}
```

The full screen is something like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2EzPF.jpg)
But when the screen is smaller, the absolute positioned element moves, like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bP5OU.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if you want an image to appear on top of another in an exact spot you should try vw and vh(vertical width, vertical heigh), i remember making something work like that.
If that doesn't solve your problem you should use px, and detect the size of the screen with javascript so you know where to place the elements.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I already tried with vh and vw, but I got the same result... And you you know how to do this with JS?

Comment: I'm at work right now so i can't elaborate on the code, but when I get home in about 8 hours if nobody solved your problem I'll see what i can do.

Comment: That would be great! Thank you very much! In the meantime, I will keep trying to solve it, so if I can make it, I'll let you know.

Comment: It just got to my head that you maybe are not resizing the second element with % you are using vw for one and % for the other try and use % for both, as well as 200px for the div may be interfering with it, change everything to %

Answer (score 0):

I think that CSS Transform-translate is rather helpful in aligning elements? Maybe you give it a try? You can define that the small picture always stay about 25% of the height of the big picture:

```
#clicked1 .box {
  transform:translateY(25%);
  transform:translateX(25%);
}
```

More info: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp. I don't have your image source so i couldn't try. But hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you! I've tried that, but unfortunately with the same result as my example...

Answer (score 0):

Searching for absolutely positioning elements over a background image I came to this question. Hope my inquiries help others that end up here.

You could use a nice combination of CSS tricks to get a pretty well behaved way of positioning elements over an image in any device/display: **Look at the snippet below**

Note that everything outside the container is sized by `vh`, witch is the viewport height. That could be done also with `vw` (viewport width) and I use some [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries#device-aspect-ratio) to detect the aspect ratio.

Inside the container you can use percentages safely. Look at `.positioned` element. Element size is in `vh` (or `vw`) and position is always in `%` from top-left.

The snippet also uses a clever `transform: translate(-50%, -50%);` to center the container on viewport.

```css
body {
  background-color: #404040;/* optional, to see position */
}
.container {
  background-image:    url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/2EzPF.jpg);
  background-size:     cover;
  height:90vh;
  width:90vh;
  background-repeat:   no-repeat;
  /* Center the container */
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%); /* magic of transform */
}
.positioned {
  background-image:    url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/jpkTo.png);
  background-size:     cover;
  height:10vh;
  width:10vh;
  position: absolute;
  top: 58%; /* Positioned on bottom left corner of factory*/
  left: 33%; /* Positioned on bottom left corner of factory*/
  opacity: 0.8; /* optional, to see position */
}
.positioned:hover {
  background-image: none;  /* optional, to see position */
}
@media (max-aspect-ratio: 1/1) {
  /* css for vertical viewport */
  .container {
    height:90vw;
    width:90vw;
  }
  .positioned {
    height:10vw;
    width:10vw;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="positioned"></div>
</div>
```